# How do I schedule a launchd task?

Tags: macos

I want to run a python script every day at 7pm on a mac-based computer. I put together a script, but I'm not sure where to save it or where I can monitor progress. What can I do to turn this into a task-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.nightlyscript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/python</string>
        <string>/path/to/script.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>19</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this excellent article at townrdsdatascience.com](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-scheduling-tasks-for-your-data-science-project-d7df4531fc41#bfcb), you need to put your property list in the `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directory (which you can create in `~/Library` if it doesn't already exist. The [launchd man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/launchd.plist/) further explains that you can put it in `/Library/LaunchAgents` if you want it to run for each user on your machine, or in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` to make it run across the whole system. Be sure to check your plist against the instructions in either of those sources -- I haven't looked to see if you've included everything that's needed. You'll also want to make your python script executable.

Comment: Great and is the plist right otherwise? I want to make sure I got the property list url correct

Comment: @Cauder It looks OK to me, but you should run it through `plutil` to validate it as a property list. After that, I'd try it out according to the linked instructions and see if it does what you want. As with other kinds of code, just because it's valid doesn't mean that it does the correct thing, so you'll need to test it.

Comment: Depending on where the script and any files it accesses are, you may also need to grant it an exception to privacy protection, which is a bit of a job (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys)). If possible, make sure the script & its files aren't in private areas of your user account.